# .mo and .po files for wordpress theme internationalization

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, qtranslate

Ok, so I feel like a complete idiot asking this, but I've been looking around and I haven't found a decent answer.

I am using qTranslate as i18n plugin to create a multilingual website.

I have a localized framework/theme with a default.po file. I have built both en_CA.po/.mo and fr_FR.po/.mo files.

What do I do with these and how do I activate them?????

I have tried defining WPLANG in wp-config.php, with no result...

English is already the default one so it works fine, but the French one doesn't apply when switching form english to french... I still get the english text for theme strings (content translates fine)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I figured out it appeared to be a setting in qTranslate that set both locales to en_US and fr_FR instead of en_CA and fr_CA

Thanks.

Comment: I will answer this question in 8 hours (when allowed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it appeared to be a setting in qTranslate that set both locales to en_US and fr_FR instead of en_CA and fr_CA

Thanks.